# Сохранить картинки квадратными

Tags: php, изображения

Нужно картинки сохранить квадратными. Нашел скрипт и пробовал запустить у себя вот [этот](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=graph&page=017) код, но не сработал ни на винде ни на линуксе, `php_gd2.dll` есть. Никто не пробовал у себя этот скрипт или может быть есть другие?

Comment: Мне недавно понадобился такой скрипт - я написал вручную, сверяясь как раз со статьей на php.su, правда другой, вот этой: http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=graph&page=014

Comment: спасибо, да, похоже придется самому пилить скрипт)